# PHP session token on form submission

Tags: php, session, token

Ahoy ye gurus of the interwebz,

I'm following a tutorial on creating a secured user login/registration system that can be found here:
[PHP OOP Login/Registration System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yrpRfdtYc4)

The issue I'm having is that the form is being processed on a separate .php file not the one where the form is hosted like in the video.

Upon submitting(form.php):

a Token class is invoked from book.php:

```
if(Input::exists()) {

if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
//execute code here
}
```

Token class invoked (Token.php)

```
class Token {
public static function generate() {
    return Session::put(Config::get('session/token_name'), md5(uniqid()));
}

public static function check($token) {
    $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');

    if(Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)) {
        //Session::delete($tokenName);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

the problem I'm having is that if I do not comment

```
//Session::delete($tokenName);
```

the token is being deleted on subsequent form submissions.

The post is being done through jquery/ajax from form.php thus the initial token does not get refreshed when the form is reloaded with error messages.
On the next submit the $tokenName has already been deleted from the previous call invalidating the condition or at least that's what I think is happening.
Since on any subsequent submits, book.php no longer executes the code in here:

```
if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
//execute code here
}
```

Am I ok by just commenting out and ignoring

```
Session::delete($tokenName);
```

or should i go a different way about it?

Newbie here so please take it easy on me...

Comment: What you suggest sounds correct. Later ajax calls would send over the same old token and it has been deleted. It wouldn't hurt to just not delete the token and leave it in the session. It's not ideal, but doesn't hurt. At least you are using a token.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, that is exactly what I was thinking but was seeking confirmation from someone more experienced. Would there be any security concerns doing it this way? Any way that token could be hijacked and even so, could it be used somehow to bypass the post?

Comment: If you wanted to be a little more secure about it, every few requests just generate a new token, store it in session and send it back. On the client if you see the token in the ajax response, overwrite the token value you are sending with future ajax requests.

Comment: The whole point of the token is to prevent other websites from posing as your form. Anyone can create a form on a website that looks like yours and point it at your site. When someone fills out the form and submits it, it looks to your site as just a normal request. The point of the token is that the form can send over a token, but it won't be the same as the token in your session. My bad website can't access your session to get the expected token for you to submit the form. So I can't forge a request from my website looking like you. Regardless if it is the same token for each request.

Comment: How would I go about refreshing the token with ajax? if you don't mind my ignorance...

Comment: That would depend on several things. How are you doing the ajax requests? using a library like jquery? How are you generating the tokens now on the server? How are you storing the token currently on the client side for sending it over to the server?

Comment: btw, thanks for the thorough explanation, I kind of understood the whole purpose of using a token but now it makes perfect sense. would there even be a point in refreshing that token thru ajax? and if so would you be so kind in pointing me in the right direction on how to do that?

Comment: token is generated in form.php like so: <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">

Comment: jquery/ajax post is like so: $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "book.php",
  data: {name: name, etc: etc, etc: etc, token: token}

Comment: where var token = $("#token").val();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128200/discussion-between-cnapsys-and-jonathan-kuhn).